# How do I use C# generic Dictionary like the Hashtable is used in Java?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am following this [tutorial](http://ghoscher.me/2012/03/23/mapapp4-tilesprovider/) and I am working with the Dictionary that I have found out is the equivalent to the Hashtable in Java.

I created my Dictionary like so:

```
private Dictionary<String, Tile> tiles = new Dictionary<String, Tile>();
```

Though my dilemma is that when using Dictionary I can not use get, written in Java like so:

```
Tile tile = tiles.get(x + ":" + y);
```

How do I accomplish the same thing. Meaning getting x:y as the result?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It seems on topic and it's hard to find if we're not experienced with reading the MSDN documentation. The link you provided helps but it doesn't answer the user's question, which is looking for an equivalent in C# to what exists in Java. Saying that it's trivial isn't fair nor realistic and is unnecessarily discouraging. We need programmers, and saying RTFM doesn't help.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel and other closers: Shaun has posted about this closure in [a question on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294325/603977).

Comment: You should be a bit more careful with your question title: "as the Hashtable in Java" sounds like you want to actually use the C# dictionary in Java, which is of course a silly question.  Think about the people who are looking at the question list.  They will see your question title and think "that's dumb, I'd better go downvote and close it"

Comment: You might want to explain how you want it, and not by pointing to another language+standard-library.

Comment: I would like to change the question more to peoples liking but I did include that I need it written x:y, the tutorial I included might not seem to be in need to be read but it explains the problem, I don't want to change the question as every time it gets changed more people look at it and dislike it and that stresses me out as I already got answers that combined I understand. x:y is what you use in a map to show longitude and latitude. I looked at MSDN for hours, including other questions on SO to and other sites. This problem has been there for months with several people looking into it.

Comment: And thank you Shaun Luttin and sorry all others who dislike this question, I hope it helps someone like me at some point though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Short Answer

Use the [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or the [`TryGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. If the key isn't present, then the former throws a [`KeyNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the latter returns false.

There is really no direct equivalent to the Java `Hashtable` [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method. That's because Java's `get()` returns null if the key isn't present.

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

On the other hand, in C# we can map a key to a null value. If either the indexer or the `TryGetValue()` says that the value associated with a key is null, then that doesn't mean the key isn't mapped. It just means that the key is mapped to null.

## [Running Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MegSLa):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<String, Tile> tiles = new Dictionary<String, Tile>();
    public static void Main()
    {
        // add two items to the dictionary
        tiles.Add("x", new Tile { Name = "y" });
        tiles.Add("x:null", null);

        // indexer access
        var value1 = tiles["x"];
        Console.WriteLine(value1.Name);

        // TryGetValue access
        Tile value2;
        tiles.TryGetValue("x", out value2);
        Console.WriteLine(value2.Name);

        // indexer access of a null value
        var value3 = tiles["x:null"];
        Console.WriteLine(value3 == null);

        // TryGetValue access with a null value
        Tile value4;
        tiles.TryGetValue("x:null", out value4);
        Console.WriteLine(value4 == null);

        // indexer access with the key not present
        try
        {
            var n1 = tiles["nope"];     
        }
        catch(KeyNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        // TryGetValue access with the key not present      
        Tile n2;
        var result = tiles.TryGetValue("nope", out n2);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(n2 == null);
    }

    public class Tile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `HashMap#get` returns null on key-lookup failure while `Dictionary#[]` throws an exception. Also the "key" value (`x + ":" + y`) is created the same in both languages..

Comment: @user2864740 if get returns null, how does one know whether a null value has been stored in association with the passed key, or the passed key is absent from the hashtable?

Comment: If you're using the indexer and null returns, then you know that null has been stored in association with the key. That's because if the key is absent, there will be an exception. On the other hand, if you use `TryGetValue`, it will return false if the key doesn't exist. So that's how you'd know.,

Comment: @JeroenVannevel and other closers: Shaun has posted about this closure in [a question on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294325/603977).

Comment: @phoog `HashMap#containsKey` can be used first and/or in conjunction. It's Just One Of Those Things in Java .. it's too late in the day for me to get worked up about `null` :-D (Java 8 introduces `#getOrDefault` which would allow the use of a non-null sentinel value as an alternative approach.)

Answer (score 2):

Best way to get value is

```
 bool Dictionary<Key, Value>.TryGetValue(Key key, out Value value);
```

It will return boolean value to determine if `key` was present and `value` is correctly referenced or not.

This method is fast, since you get out `value` only when key was presented, so multiple hashing and dictionary searching is avoided.

So your code will be:

```
private Dictionary<String, Tile> tiles = new Dictionary<String, Tile>();
Tile outValue;
if(tiles.TryGetValue( x + ":" + y, out outValue))
{
     Console.WriteLine("I have this: " + outValue.ToString());
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("I have nothing");
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).